# MySQL - Selecting data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm  new to MySQL, and cannot seem to get the desired information out, after trying a few different google searches, and reading through some MySQL tutorials.

Given the following sample tables:

Table 1(Activity This is activity table which is send to the clients):

```
ID  sendingid         list        fromaccount    
1       a1        user_new1        noreply@example.com
2       a2        user_new1        noreply@example.com
3       a3        user_new2        noreply@example.com
4       a4        user_new4        noreply@example.com
```

Table 2(Tracking - This is the main task tracking table,which track which user opened our activity):

```
ID  trackingid         emails            
1       a1        myexampla@gmail.com
2       a2        example@hotmail.com 
3       a3        newexample@yahoo.com
4       a4        simpler@gmail.com
```

Table 3(user_new1- This is the list which is attached with activity send under the column name list):

```
ID     fname         emails                    price
1       John        myexampla@gmail.com        10
2       Bill        example@hotmail.com        20
3       sami        newexample@yahoo.com       20
4       daweoo        simpler@gmail.com        20
```

The user_new1,user_new2,user_new3 .......user_new80 tables. All tables have similar structure.

first i will find unique email address from tracking table then  i find to which list of the activity table it is send,
then i will delete that record from list say user_new1 and move it to another temprary table.
we have millions of records in database

Answer (score 0):

About tables user_new1, user_new2 ... 
Is it really good idea to create a table for each user? Not just table which have fields for each user.

You can select data from multiple tables by using JOIN - [JOINS on w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

But you need to connect tables, for example, create table Users and Jobs. User is having one job. So in user table add field job_id and set as a foreign key to job table, if using InnoDB engine.
After that you can use join to select from both table:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users AS u
        JOIN jobs AS j
        ON u.job_id = j.id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 SELECT
    p.fCodigoProduto, p.fCodigoCategoria, p.fCodigoCategoriaSub, p.fCodigoVendedor,
    p.fCodigoFornecedor, p.fNomeProduto, p.fDescricao, p.fPreco,
    p.fObservacao, p.fDataCadastro, p.fStatusProduto,
    c.fNomeCategoria, 
    s.fNomeCategoriaSub,
    f.fNomeFornecedor, 
    i.fSequenciaImagem, i.fCaminhoImagem, i.fTamanhoImagem, i.fImagemProduto,
    (@rownum:=@rownum+1) as Rownumber,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM tblprodutos) as QtdeReg
 FROM
  tblprodutos p
  LEFT JOIN tblcategorias c ON p.fCodigoCategoria = c.fCodigoCategoria
  LEFT JOIN tblcategoriassub s ON p.fCodigoCategoriaSub = s.fCodigoCategoriaSub
  LEFT JOIN tblvendedores v ON p.fCodigoVendedor = v.fCodigoVendedor
  LEFT JOIN tblfornecedores f ON p.fCodigoFornecedor = f.fCodigoFornecedor
  LEFT JOIN tblimagemproduto i ON p.fCodigoProduto = i.fCodigoProduto
 ORDER BY
   fNomeProduto ASC
```